# Where do the dependencies javaWs, javaJpa, etc. come from in Play/Java application?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I am starting a new project in Play Framework with Java. I checked the `build.sbt` file and couldn't understand where the dependencies names came from?

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa
}
```

Where did these names like `javaWs`, `javaJpa`, etc. com from? How to check the version of these libraries?

Comment: May I ask to approve the answer that has ultimately worked for you, if any, or seek more details with additional questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies listed in this example are the ones that are shipped with your installation of play. The versions match the Play framework version you are using.

Play framework is modular so you don't have to use all of its modules in your application. That is why you must specify which modules you want.

Answer (score 8):

**tl;dr** They're defined by the `sbt-plugin` (see [javaWs](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala#L39) and [javaJpa](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala#L29) or others in [PlayImport.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala)) that's *usually* added to the build in `project/plugins.sbt`.

Use `sbt` or `activator` tools to learn where the build parts come from. I assume you use `sbt` (but the following applies to `activator` or `play` command line tools, too).

Mind that a sbt build is described using Scala language and all sbt builds are type-safe and compiled using the Scala compiler.

A sbt plugin is just a bunch of settings that can be applied to a project, that can also define Scala `val`s that correspond to the different dependencies you can use for a Play project, e.g. `javaJdbc`. You can query for the `val`s using `consoleProject` (that I described below as the second option).

### sbt shell

Inside the project, execute `sbt`. While in the sbt shell, execute `show libraryDependencies` to learn about the dependencies:

```
> show libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1, com.typesafe.play:twirl-api:1.0.2, com.typesafe.play:play:2.3.2, com.typesafe.play:play-test:2.3.2:test, com.typesafe.play:play-docs:2.3.2:docs, com.typesafe.play:play-jdbc:2.3.2, com.typesafe.play:anorm:2.3.2, com.typesafe.play:play-cache:2.3.2, com.typesafe.play:play-ws:2.3.2)
```

### consoleProject

Inside the project, execute `sbt consoleProject` to learn about the build. I'm using Scala-version of a Play project.

With `consoleProject` you enter a Scala REPL with the build loaded. You're in Scala REPL and you can query the different parts of the build using Scala.

Use `eval` macro to evaluate build settings inside `consoleProject`:

```
scala> libraryDependencies.eval
res0: Seq[sbt.ModuleID] = List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1, com.typesafe.play:twirl-api:1.0.2, com.typesafe.play:play:2.3.2, com.typesafe.play:play-test:2.3.2:test, com.typesafe.play:play-docs:2.3.2:docs, com.typesafe.play:play-jdbc:2.3.2, com.typesafe.play:anorm:2.3.2, com.typesafe.play:play-cache:2.3.2, com.typesafe.play:play-ws:2.3.2)
```

You get `Seq[sbt.ModuleID]` and you can do whatever you want with the value using Scala.

Since `build.sbt` for the project looks as follows (I showed only the part with `libraryDependencies`):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)
```

when in `consoleProject` I can ask what the names point to as follows:

```
scala> jdbc
res0: sbt.ModuleID = com.typesafe.play:play-jdbc:2.3.2
```

Remember, they're Scala `val`s of `sbt.ModuleID` type and...nothing more than that.

Comment: The links are dead. Unfortunately.