# Play 2.3.x libraryDependencies predefined Keys

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, dependency-management

I am exploring Play framework and SBT and I have noticed tutorials often include a set static keys such as `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJdbc, javaEbean, cache, javaWs)`.

I understand they are connected to SBT-managed dependencies and I understand how can one add such a dependency by providing maven/ivy coordinates for a given dependency but these are something different.

I would like to know more about them and my guess/understanding is they represent modules of Play framework and also specify transitive dependencies needed for correct functioning of module. However, even though I have tried to find an exhaustive list of these modules with explanations and dependencies they include, so far I haven't been able to find anything conclusive in either Play/SBT documentation.

Is there such a list? How are these static keys referred to in Play lingo? What is this concept called in SBT?

EDIT: I have found they correspond to modules in [com.typesafe.play](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play) however I haven't been able to find where is the list of `libraryDependencies` literals from above defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do the dependencies javaWs, javaJpa, etc. come from in Play/Java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055469/where-do-the-dependencies-javaws-javajpa-etc-come-from-in-play-java-applicati)

Comment: Probably, but I believe the comments on the answer are valuable as well as they indicate precisely how the whole thing is working plus it points out the exact source class which holds these values. If we could somehow aggregate the two questions/answers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25063872/1305344 where the exact source class is presented. What else is missing in the other answer (mine actually) that this has? I see no additional value.

Comment: Fair enough - I was referring to `Dependencies.scala`. In addition, I find my comment gives a short and concise overview how the whole thing is working, without delving into too much details. That is my personal opinion, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play is actually an sbt *auto-plugin*. Auto-plugins allow you to define *auto imports*, which in turn is an object whose contents are put into scope (of your `build.sbt`) automatically. Play auto-imports its sub-modules and some other useful stuff.

You can find the full list in [sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala#L14).

Comment: Thank you sir, again easy points for you but very valuable info for me :) Correct me if I am wrong(being relatively new to Scala), so we're referencing the exposed vals as elements in `libraryDependencies` which are just shorthands for defining the play module dependencies ourselves (through exact maven coordinates). The dependencies I see on the classpath of the project (e.g. Spring framework beans) are merely transitive dependencies of a particular Play module that has been added to the `libraryDependencies` sequence?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can check the file `Dependencies.scala` to see what deps each Play module has.