# EclipseLink @SQLResultSetMapping to POJO is missing

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, sqlresultsetmapping

In EclipseLink 2.5 (JPA 2.1), I'm trying to map the results of a native query to a POJO, which according to these links should be possible:

- [JPA : How to convert a native query result set to POJO class collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection/13013323#13013323)
- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html

...using this syntax (taken straight from EclipseLink 2.5 api docs):

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
      "SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(o) as orderCount, AVG(o.price) AS avgOrder " +
      "FROM Customer c, Orders o " +
      "WHERE o.cid = c.id " +
      "GROUP BY c.id, c.name",
      "CustomerDetailsResult");

@SqlResultSetMapping(
       name="CustomerDetailsResult",
       classes={
          @ConstructorResult(
               targetClass=com.acme.CustomerDetails.class,
                 columns={
                    @ColumnResult(name="id"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="orderCount"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="avgOrder", type=Double.class)
                    }
          )
       }
      )
```

However, the "classes" attribute of the @SqlResultSetMapping is not found.  I tried with Eclipselink 2.5.2, and 2.6.  Is there another (optional) EclipseLink jar I must use to get that functionality?

Comment: Looks like this guide is outdated, try http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html

Comment: How can you tell it's outdated?  My link is for EclipseLink 2.5.  Your link doesn't even say which implementation or version of JPA it's for.  And besides, both links indicate that the "classes" property of SqlResultSetMapping exists, so I'm not sure what your suggestion is.

Comment: Sometimes people mistakenly annotate the POJO with `@SqlResultSetMapping`. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25202635/3796586 and tell me if that's your case.

Comment: are you sure you imported javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping not some other annotation. I just tried with your code as it is and it worked.

Comment: Could you be using the JPA 1 jar on your classpath?

Comment: @zbig You stated in another question that, "Mapping to POJO class with @ ConstructorResult was added in version 2.1 of JPA. POJO used with the mapping has to have correct constructor.".  That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Here is your answer that I'm quoting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179180/jpa-joining-two-tables-in-non-entity-class/25184489#25184489

Comment: @Chris I'm am using the play framework, and importing eclipselink 2.5.2, which is based on JPA 2.1.  Here's the config line from my Play framework build.sbt:  "org.eclipse.persistence" % "eclipselink" % "2.5.2",

Comment: Eclipselink implements the 2.1 spec, but your issue is with the javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping class - You still need to be using the JPA 2.1 jar.  The version you have must be an earlier version of the JPA jar.  The persistence jar includes all the interfaces within the specification, such as SqlResultSetMapping, while the EclipseLink and other provider jars include backward compatible implementation classes.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, that's very good to know. It looks like [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055469/where-do-the-dependencies-javaws-javajpa-etc-come-from-in-play-java-applicati) might be related to my problem.  Even though I'm using EclipseLink 2.5.2 library, maybe the JPA jar that is provided by JavaJPA in build.sbt implements and earlier JPA spec.  But I don't have enough reputation to comment on that conversation.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you are getting your jars.  You need to include javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar within the EclipseLink installer jar on your classpath (taken from the EL 2.6 install bundle) before other persistence jars.